# How do I DRY-ly handle multiple upload types with Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to allow my users to be able to upload videos, documents & images to s3.

I was thinking that rather than having a model for each and then having 3 different uploader classes, I would just have 1 generic uploader and just whitelist all of those filetypes.

But I am not sure if that's the best approach, from a security perspective?

Also, there may be small variations with each type. For instance, with `video` a user should be able to both upload a video, or alternatively provide a YouTube link.

What's the most Rails/DRY-way to approach this?

Comment: This is one of those more complex issues which is beyond the scope of convention. There are many ways to solve this issue (STI, MTI, dynamic columns, etc) - each with their own pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a generic type then have sub types using STI ([Single Table Inheritance](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/)). Unless you feel that the sub types would be so different from one another that there will be a lot of empty columns in some sub-types and not others this seems like the best way to go. From a security standpoint I don’t see how there is really any significant impact in that regards.

```
class FileUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
end


class Video < FileUpload
end

class Image < FileUpload
end

class Document < FileUpload
end
```

There is however a reasonable case for not doing this. Usually the rule of thumb for inheritance is if something is a type of, but in this case there is some gray area. The ambiguity comes from the fact that yes a document is a type of uploadable file but its not a type of video. So you want it to have the behavior of an uploadable file just like video but thats where the similarities cease. So the better route is probably to create an upload able [module](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)  that has all the desire share behavior and include that in the three models and let them all be their on thing.

```
module Uploadable
end


class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uploadable
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uploadable
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Uploadable
end
```

Comment: Hey I don't know if you have read this book yet but this will give you a lot of insight in to the DRY concept. https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Object-Oriented-Design-Ruby-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321721330/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1476831726&sr=1-1&keywords=practical+object-oriented+design+in+ruby

Comment: I have had it on my wishlist for some time, just haven't gotten around to doing it yet. Thanks for the reminder though.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using STI as mentioned by `C dot` you could also have a `jsonb` column in you model, this would make it possible to store whatever you want in that field.

Here's a good read on this topic:
http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

```
t.jsonb :videos, null: false, default: '{}'

user = User.create({
  videos: {
    vimeo: 'https://vimeo.com/123',
    file: 'http://example.com/123.mp4',
    youtube: 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=123'
  }
})
```

Might be an option to consider for your issue.

Comment: The big question is however if you can use JSONB with carrierwave without tearing it to shreds.